# Does fwrite flush the buffer on '\n'?

Tags: c, stm32, stdio, newlib

I have my own implementation of `_open()`, `_close()`, `_write()`, `_read()`.

My code:

```
FILE *f = fopen("0:test", "wb");  // calls _open()
fwrite("hello ", 6, 1, f);
fwrite("world\r\n\0", 8, 1, f); // calls _write(3, "hello world\r\n", 13)
fflush(f);                      // calls _write(3, "\0", 1)
fclose(f);                      // calls _close(3)
```

`BUFSIZE` is 1024

Compiler: `arm-none-eabi-gcc`/ Version: `5.4.1`

Why does `fwrite()` interpret `'\n'` even though I have the flags `"wb"`?

Does `fopen()` interpret the filename `"0:test"`?

Comment: it depends on the buffering mode - see `setvbuf()` and friends...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does `fwrite()` interpret `'\n'` even though I have the flags `"wb"`?

Because the stream is line buffered. Whether a stream would become line buffered or not is not determined by the flags passed to `fopen()`.

The toolchain you are using ships with Red Hat's newlib, which calls the `isatty()` function at the first attempt to read from or write to the stream. If `isatty()` returns a nonzero value, then the stream will be line buffered.

If you don't like it, you can modify `_isatty()` to return `0`, or call `setvbuf()` after `fopen()`.

> Does `fopen()` interpret the filename `"0:test"`?

No, any filename will be passed on directly to `_open()`.